# display data from multiple tables and foreign keys in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-blade

I have two tables :

**bonhomme**

```
+----+--------------+
| id |     name     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Alec Badwin  |
|  2 | Maria Quiban |
+----+--------------+
```

**serie**

```
+----+---------------+
| id |     name      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | 30 Rock       |
|  2 | Good Day L.A. |
+----+---------------+
```

I have another one called : **serie_personnage**

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------------+
| id | bonhomme_id | serie_id |  personnage  |
+----+-------------+----------+--------------+
|  1 |           1 |        1 | Jack Donaghy |
|  2 |           2 |        2 | Maria Quiban |
+----+-------------+----------+--------------+
```

I want to display the personnage from serie_personnage and link it in my blade with the name of the bonhomme (in my table bonhomme) associated.

In other words, I want a table in my blade with rows where there is in column 1, the name of the bonhomme and in column 2, the personnage associated.

How can I do that with the relationships in Laravel ? I've tried it but it's not working well.

Controller

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $serie = Serie::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('admin.series.castings.show')->withSerie($serie);
}
```

Model - Serie

```php
public function personnages() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\SeriePersonnage');
}

public function acteurs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Admin\Bonhomme', 'serie_personnage', 'serie_id', 'bonhomme_id');
}
```

Blade

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach($serie->acteurs as $acteur)  
    @foreach($serie->personnages as $personnage) 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $acteur->nom }}</td>
        <td>{{ $personnage->personnage }}</td>
        <td><a href="#">bla</a></td>
        <td>{{ $personnage->rang }}</td>
        <td class="has-text-right">
            <a class="button is-outlined" href="{{ route('series.show', $serie->id) }}">
                Voir
            </a>
            <a class="button is-outlined" href="#">Editer</a>
        </td>
    </tr> 

    @endforeach
    @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

[My Table in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC58y.jpg)

Comment: Did you try using a [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between your `bonhomme` and `serie` table? From what I see, `serie_personnage` works as a pivot table, so you could set it up like that and retrieve the data from `serie`

Comment: Do you have any relationships set up for your model serie_personnage?

Comment: I already tried the many to many relationship but i'm not sure that i make it right...
What would be the right syntax for that in the models and how could i retrieve the data in my blade ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to help you as French developer as-well! First of all, I would change your controller for a more simple way to get the Serie :

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $serie = Serie::findOrFail($id);
    return view('admin.series.castings.show')->withSerie($serie);
}
```

EDIT: I use `Model::findOrFail($id);` because it throws a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException`. If you don't catch the exception, Laravel will automatically send a 404 HTTP response. It prevent the user to have an error using an obsolete link. [See the doc for more informations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

Then I don't think it is a good idea to use `foreach` loop twice... I would rather use only one `foreach` loop on the personnages. Then, I would get the actor of the character from the Personnage model. It should looks like the code below:

**App\Models\Admin\SeriePersonnage.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Admin;

use App\Models\Admin\Bonhomme;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SeriePersonnage extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        //Whatever you want to put here
    ];

    /**
     * Gets the actor of the character     
     */
    public function actor() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Bonhomme::class);
    }
}
```

Then in your blade view:

```php
<tbody>

@foreach($serie->personnages as $personnage) 
<tr> 
  <td>{{$personnage->actor->nom}}</td>
  <td>{{$personnage->personnage}}</td>
  <td><a href="#">bla</a></td>
  <td>{{$personnage->rang}}</td>
  <td class="has-text-right"><a class="button is-outlined" href="{{route('series.show', $serie->id)}}">Voir</a>  <a class="button is-outlined" href="#">Editer</a></td>
</tr> 

@endforeach
</tbody>
```

You might also add a `personnages()` methods in your actor model so that you would be able to get all the characters this actor is playing.

Also I would advice you to use English words for variable names, class names and in fact every word in your code, especially if you post for help on English websites. I would also recommend you to change SeriePersonnage to only Personnage if you only manage series (you might also handle movies, Japanese Anime etc, in this case you can ignore my message). Also it would be great to change the row name of serie_personnage from `personnage` to `nom`.

Hope it helped you and I didn't do mistakes :P

Comment: Hi Alexandre, thanks a lot for your answer and all the tips ! I'm new in Laravel and in dev in general so it's always a good thing when someone give me tips ! 
I tried your solution but I have a "Trying to get property 'nom' of non-object" error when i reach {{personnage->actor->nom}} :(

Comment: Well did you add the actor() method on the Model of personnage ?

Comment: Yes, i've put 
public function actor() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Bonhomme::class);
}
in my SeriePersonnage model

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong and it's driving me crazy !

Comment: Try to see what's inside your `$personnage` object with `dd($personnage)` and let's see what you get. I might wrote some mistake

Comment: SeriePersonnage {#674 ▼
  #table: "serie_personnage"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "bonhomme_id" => 50
    "serie_id" => 2
    "personnage" => "jok"
    "rang" => 1
  ]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: Well, I use a bit of my time to try on my side and it works fine... I give you a link [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/AlexandreGerault/charlotte). Hope you will find your mistake in my code. When it's done, tell on your subject ;)

Comment: Haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan it's working !! Thank you so much... i was going insane with this !! I'm gonna clean my models now with the right naming, more user friendly, thanks so much again !